# How to limit NSURLCache disk size

Tags: ios, swift, caching, uiwebview, nsurlcache

I have an app that uses UIWebView to browse websites, after some time I noticed that the cache size of the device is too huge, with some devices it could reach multiple Gaga Bytes

I found that the following folder `AppData/Library/Caches/com.myApp/fsCachedData/` is growing with time

Mainly I think the problem happens when navigating through website that sets cache policy to the requests with very big `max-age` for example [h&m](http://www.hm.com/de/product/63681?article=63681-A) website has `max-age=31536000` for the item images

I am using the default `NSURLCache` without any modifications, but when I tried to limit the desk capacity as the mentioned [here](http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/), it didn't prevent the cache size from expanding over the limit

```
let URLCache = NSURLCache(memoryCapacity: 4 * 1024 * 1024, diskCapacity: 20 * 1024 * 1024, diskPath: nil)
    NSURLCache.setSharedURLCache(URLCache)
```

Any idea how to solve this problem and enforce the system to purge all old cache files automatically?

Note that I am search for a more optimized solution than clearing all the cache using `NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()`

Answer (score 0):

We had the exact same issue. The app's memory usage was going up from 100Mb to 500Mb.

The fix was to not use `UIWebview` and just use `WKWebview`. After that the memory usage was normal